# chained variable with a non chained?

Tags: optaplanner

is it OK to have a chained variable field + another, non chained one, in the same planning entity ?

example :

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"amountToTradeRange"})
long amountToTrade;  

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"componentsRange", "transactionsRange"}, graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
ITransactionComponent prevComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, an entity can have as many planning variables as you need and they can combine any type.

That being said, it does impact the search space.